# Count how many times row type 1 is found between row type 2 dates

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'am making a report in which I have to find out how many times there has been a situation where one or more row type 1 is found between row type 2 dates. Data looks like this and is sorted by date:

```
Date          Row type
2014-01-17    2
2014-01-21    1*
2014-02-06    2
2014-02-11    1*
2014-02-20    1*
2014-03-19    1*
2014-03-19    1* 
2014-03-19    2
2014-03-19    1*
2014-03-19    1*
2014-03-20    1* 
2014-03-20    2
2014-03-20    2
2014-03-21    1*
2014-03-21    2
2014-03-21    2
2014-03-21    1*
2014-03-24    1*
2014-03-24    1*
2014-03-25    2
```

So here I can see that type 1 rows can be found between type 2 rows five times.

I only have used very basic SQL queries and I have no idea how to proceed with this. Query should be able to run in SSRS report.

Any help ? Or if somebody could point to right direction, I have looked at WITH CRE and RANK OVER but I can not figure out could these be solution to this problem.

Comment: Which language you are using to show this data there you can build logic for it.

Comment: I think my options for this are limited to T-SQL when defining dataset  for report or in SSRS or maybe some feature in SSRS which I am not aware of

Comment: How do you know the order of items when they have the same date?

Comment: Good question, did not think this trough when making this example. But in actual dataset there is also precise time and these times never overlap, datatype is datetime in actual data.

Comment: I have got sweet & short solution for this, please check below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
WITH AllRowNumbers AS (
    SELECT RowType
          ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY [Date]) AS RowNumber
    FROM #T
)
,Type2RowNumbers AS (
    SELECT RowNumber
    FROM AllRowNumbers
    WHERE RowType = 2
)
,Gaps AS (
    SELECT RowNumber - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY RowNumber) AS Gap
    FROM Type2RowNumbers
)
SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT Gap) 
FROM Gaps
WHERE Gap > 0
```

Answer (score 1):

Here it is,...

```
;With CTE as
(
select *,Row_number() over (order by dateDt) as RNo
 from mtT
)
select COUNT(*) from CTE  as a
inner join CTE as b on a.RNo + 1 = b.RNo
    and a.rowType <> b.rowType
where a.rowType = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this will work with SSRS, but it might help.

```
SELECT t.dt BeginType2, ndt.dt EndType2, Type1.Cnt FROM tblTesting t
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT TOP 1 dt, RowType 
                FROM tblTesting t2 
                WHERE t2.dt > t.dt AND RowType = 2 
                ORDER BY dt) ndt
    CROSS APPLY (SELECT COUNT(*) Cnt 
                FROM tblTesting t3 
                WHERE t3.dt > t.dt AND t3.dt < ndt.dt AND RowType = 1) Type1
WHERE t.rowType = 2
```

Answer (score 0):

I hope this query will help you.

It counts not directly what you want, but amount of 1 and 2 in each day

```
select a,b,max(rn) over(partition by a,b)-min(rn) over(partition by a,b)+1 from (
select *, ROW_NUMBER() over(partition by b order by a) rn from 
(values ('2014-01-17 ',   2),
('2014-01-21',   1),
('2014-02-06', 2),
('2014-02-11',1),
('2014-02-20',1),
('2014-03-19',1),
('2014-03-19',1 ),
('2014-03-19',2),
('2014-03-19',1),
('2014-03-19',1),
('2014-03-20',1 ),
('2014-03-20',2),
('2014-03-20',2),
('2014-03-21',1),
('2014-03-21',2),
('2014-03-21',2),
('2014-03-21',1),
('2014-03-24',1)
) as t(a,b))t
order by a
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select sum(cnt) from 
(select a.f1 ,a.f2,case when a.f2<b.f2 then 1 else 0 end as cnt from 
(select *, row_number() OVER( ORDER BY f1) AS Rank from t1 ) a
left join(select *, row_number() OVER( ORDER BY f1) AS Rank from t1 ) b 
on a.Rank = b.Rank+1) as d
```